How to Merge rows that have duplicate values in few columns and mutually exclusive columns with nulls in pyspark?
%%pyspark
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
(1, "foo", "val1", ""),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
(1, "foo", "", "val2"),
],
["id", "label", "key1", "key2"]
)
df.show(truncate=False)
#df.na.drop().show(truncate=False)
#df.groupBy("id","label").agg(F.first("key1", ignorenulls=True))
gives following output
enter image description here
expecting following output
enter image description here
gives following output
enter image description here
expecting following output
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
